# Overflow property does not clip a content in Text widget

Tags: flutter

There is a widget

```
Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.warning,
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
    ),
  ),
  const Text(
    'Failed to fetch repos for',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),
  ),
  Text(
    store.user,
    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // here it is
  )
])
```

For some reason the `overflow` property doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: wrap your last `Text` with `Expanded`

Comment: sure, your welcome